# Passing variable into SQL script using BAT file

Tags: sql, batch-file, variables, cmd

Here is my dilemma. I cannot get my code to work. I have a batch file which executeS an SQL script. The batch file needs to be able to execute the sql script using the proper variable. Here is my batch file

```
@echo off
set list= TRA-1000 TRA-1002 TRA-1003    TRA-1004   
 for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
    @sqlplus gpms/gpms@prod112 @get_tra1098_data.sql outputfilename = %%a
 )
 @pause
```

So essentially I am trying to pass the selected item from 'list' into my sql script. Here are the relevant lines of code from my sql file:

```
    spool $(outputfilename).csv
    ...
    where  inst.instruction_doc_no in ($(outputfilename))
    ...
```

It is not working. How do I get my batch file to properly call my sql file in a loop, each time calling the sql file using the proper item in 'list'?

ps. this is what the sql file would look like if I *wasn't* trying to automate it:

```
        spool TRA-1000.csv
        ...
        where  inst.instruction_doc_no in ('TRA-1000')
        ...
```

Comment: what error are you getting, if any? You have to use setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion when using a for loop

Comment: You should comment out @echo off and see the output of each command and if it gives you any errors

Comment: @QueenSvetlana, [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is not needed as long as you do not assign and read an environment variable in the loop (or any other block or line of code)...

Comment: @aschipfl - Thanks for the clarification :D